# Loading document with DOM

Tags: javascript, html, domcontentloaded

I am new to using Javascript to Web development.
Recently, I've encountered this problem when trying to use `DOMContentLoaded` to my code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>hello</title>
  <script>
    document.addEventListner('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) => {
      document.querySelector('#red').addEventListener('click', function() {
        let button = document.querySelector('button');
        button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id='red'> Red </button>
</body>

</html>
```

When I clicked the button, the color of the button did not change

I think that I've correctly implemented my code and added `DOMContentLoaded` event when placing the `<script>` in the head of my html code. However, this code does not work and so far I still not yet figure out where does the problem lies.

Could anyone help me with this matter and give me an explaination please?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Read your errors in console! `function(event) => {` Also, Instead of using a `DOMContentLoaded` callback function, simply place your script right before the closing `</body>` tag.  Or use `defer`

Comment: `document.addEventListner` typo - `Listener`

Comment: Oh I see, did not notice that. Now the code is working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

place `<script>` in the body after the tags It's will work Good luck

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id='red'> Red </button>
  <script>
    document.addEventListner('DOMContentLoaded', function() => {
      document.querySelector('#red').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```